# Fetch all employees if not employee selected from UI else select specific employee data

Tags: mysql

I want to select all employees if no employee is selected else need data for selected employee.

I have written this query but it is throwing error.

```
DECLARE @emp_id INT

SET @emp_id=0 -- This will change based on the selected employee from UI

SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE employee_id in (CASE WHEN @emp_id=0 THEN (SELECT employee_id FROM employees) ELSE @emp_id END)
```

Sample Script for reproducing issue

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id INT ,
    first_name VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO employees values (1, '1_fname', '1_lname'),(2, '2_fname', '2_lname'),(3, '3_fname', '3_lname'),(4, '4_fname', '4_lname'),(5, '5_fname', '5_lname')
```

I want to this in single query.

Comment: Is this in stored procedure? If yes, probably you can use [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), and not CASE operator

Comment: no , it is not in stored procedure. It will be inline query. For simplicity I have put here like this.

Comment: if required I can create stored Procedure. But I am getting error on this query in workbench. how to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using prepared statements, you will need to provide the selected employee 2 times - as argument 1 and 2:

```sql
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE CASE WHEN COALESCE(?,0) = 0 THEN TRUE ELSE id = ? END
```

Comment: how this will return all employees in case of no employee selected ? Suppose I want to add some where clause in subquery then or want to select employee id from other table.

Comment: Simple - if you provide a non-zero employee ID for the prepared query, then it will return that particular employee. If you provide 0 or NULL - the query will return all records from the table `employees`, in no particular order.

Comment: but i can change inner query's table with where clause. I need employee id in inner query from different tables based on condition. From inner query I mean query in case statement in my example.

Comment: This condition must be determined outside of SQL - e.g. in PHP, Node, C# or whatever server-side language you're using. Once the condition is determined - you will issue that predefined SQL query which corresponds to the actual condition. E.g. if you want all employees - you will run `SELECT * FROM employees` but if you want a single employee - you will run `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id IN (SELECT employee_id FROM some_other_table WHERE some_other_condition)`

Answer (score 0):

For single query, we can `INNER JOIN` with same table to emulate whether employees should shown or not. Using this query will produce desired output.

```
select e.*
from employees e
inner join (
    select employee_id,
        case 
            when @emp_id = 0 then true -- will display all employees
            when @emp_id = @emp_id then true -- only display selected employee
        else false
        end as is_shown
    from employees
) filter on e.employee_id = filter.employee_id and filter.is_shown = 1;
```

Or using another approach

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name
from (
    select e.*,
        case 
            when @emp_id = 0 then true
            when @emp_id = employee_id then true
        else false
        end as is_shown
    from employees e
) employees
where is_shown = 1;
```

Simple flow control inside stored procedure

```
delimiter $$

use `precise`$$

drop procedure if exists `GetEmployee`$$

create definer=`user`@`%` procedure `GetEmployee`(empID int)
begin

case when empID = 0 then
    select *
    from employees;
else
    select *
    from employees
    where employee_id = empID;
end case
;   

end$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I want to do this in single query. Sorry for confusion. I have updated my question.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include single query.